# How to access Server side validation errors on Client side and change css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I am workig on a MVC project which is using Jquery for client side validation, like below

```
jQuery.validator.defaults.highlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if ($(element).attr('readonly')) {
                return;
            }
            element = this.findByName(element.name);
            element.parent()
                .addClass('invalid')
                .removeClass('valid');
        };
        jQuery.validator.defaults.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {

            element = this.findByName(element.name);
            element.parent()
                .removeClass('invalid')
                .addClass('valid');
            element.nextAll('.error').hide();
        };
```

With this way of validation we are showing error message which looks like this

[image]

But i have a model with a few fields which needs to be validated on the server side, so when i Post the Form i need to get the list of fields which failed validation on the server side and when i load the view again i need to change the css of the failed fields and show the error to the user, How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

On server side using a templating language you can customize html when there is error and specify what error was there. In html you could either conditionally create new elements or apply css to show hidden error. Or make some data available in javascript.

In short you change the data in html on server to indicate something went wrong and it's easy with templating engines like swig, jade and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled via the Ajax error method on the jQuery submission (this is an AJAX form post, correct?)

Something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/saveuser",
  dataType: "application/json",
  data: data,
  success: function (response) {
    console.log("Details saved successfully!!!");
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    jQuery.validator.defaults.highlight(thrownError.fieldName);
  }
});
```